# Render a video from ffmpeg frames using OpenGL

Tags: c#, android, video, opengl-es, ffmpeg

I'm wondering how can I render a video from raw RGB frames computed by ffmpeg to an OpenGL texture in Android.

My app is an Xamarin.Android project and I'm using a ffmpeg C# wrapper which is working like this:

```
while (ffmpeg.av_read_frame(pFormatContext, pPacket) >= 0)
{
    if (pPacket->stream_index == pStream->index)
    {
        if (ffmpeg.avcodec_send_packet(pCodecContext, pPacket) < 0)
        {
            ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(pPacket);
            ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pDecodedFrame);
            continue;
        }

        if (ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pDecodedFrame) < 0)
        {
            ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pDecodedFrame);
            continue;
        }

        ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(pPacket);
        var src = &pDecodedFrame->data0;
        var dst = &pConvertedFrame->data0;
        var srcStride = pDecodedFrame->linesize;
        var dstStride = pConvertedFrame->linesize;
        ffmpeg.sws_scale(pConvertContext, src, srcStride, 0, height, dst, dstStride);

        var convertedFrameAddress = pConvertedFrame->data0;

        var imageBufferPtr = new IntPtr(convertedFrameAddress);
        ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pDecodedFrame);
    }
}
```

How can I renderer the image from *imageBufferPtr* variable to an OpenGL texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I renderer the image from imageBufferPtr variable to an OpenGL texture?

By passing it as `data` paramter to `glTex{Sub}Image2D`.